# Loop through each object and return it's availability (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, loops, eloquent

I have an app where users can rent cars. The cars are already in the database put by me.

```
$table->string('name')->nullable();
$table->string('color')->nullable();
$table->string('model')->nullable();
```

Since it's a rental I have a reservation table

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->dateTime('from_date')->nullable();
$table->dateTime('to_date')->nullable();
```

I already created a function where users request a car and the function will loop and find same requted car.

And car_user to link the reserved car with the user.

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

$table->integer('car_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('car_id')->references('id')->on('cars');
```

Now when I try to save the date and time for the specifically requested car (A).I have to make sure that:

1. Same car(A) can't be reserved again in the  same time.
2. All the cars are available in the same time car (A) is reserved.

So I first came up with this function

```
public function isSlotAvailable(Request $request) {
    $appointments = Reservation::all();
    $from =  Carbon::parse( $request->from);
    $to =  Carbon::parse( $request->to);

    foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {
        $eventStart = Carbon::instance(
            new DateTime($appointment['dt_start'])
        );

        $eventEnd = Carbon::instance(
            new DateTime($appointment['dt_end'])
        )->subSecond(1);

        if ($from->between($eventStart, $eventEnd) || 
            $to->between($eventStart, $eventEnd)   || 
            ($eventStart->between($from, $to) && $eventEnd->between($from, $to))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This function will check if there is availability in the Reservation table. But it's wrong because it treats the cars as a single car. For example, if I have 5 cars available in the database and a user reserves a car from `2017-01-05 05:00:00` to `2017-01-10 09:00:00`. All the cars will be reserved in the same time because the loop does not go through each car like `$car->allreservation` .

**Question**

how can I loop in each car and check if the new requested date overlaps? and if it overlaps it will go to the second car and check and if not then it will link it to the user.

Really appreciate your help

**UPDATE**

This is how I save the new requested car

```
 $id = $new_car->id;
 $Reservation_id = $time->id;
 $user->cars()->attach($id, ['type' => 'requested']);
 $user->reservations()->attach(Reservation_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you are using DATETIME datatype in database table not using TIMESTAMP CURRENT_TIME_STAMP.

If you are using current time stamp then change it to DATETIME and save the form date field value in loop. I hope it will work!

Comment: I'm storing the date and time in one entity as DATETIME in Reservation. Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 1):

As it seems to me what you need is a better database design.

As it seems you have same car with different quantities (is that? If not please comment Or is this car id is something like real car id? => it is unique)

If so what you need is a proper way to handle the database. In this case you have to implement a one to many relationship(Same id car having multiple instances). 
If this is the case you might need to add another field to the car; something like car quantity. Then you can check the reserved cars against the total quantity. Then if the number of reserved cars are less than what you have it can be reserved.

If it is other way around( each car having unique id - no repeating number of cars with same id);
then when you check whether slot is available for the car, get all the reservations for that car and check whether it is having the same (or between) reservation.
If this is not what you are looking for please comment.

**Edit**

You may need to consider some about Database normalization. Go through the tutorial [here at tutorials-point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm)

1. First add the car id to the reservation table.
2. Add User Id to the reservation table.
3. Then you can get the reservations for that car as described below.
4. Check whether your reservation is in the retrieved reservations.

In laravel you can write select queries like

```
$reservations= DB::table('reservations')->where('car_id', '=', 100)->get()  // if car_id = 100
```

To read more about laravel database queries refer the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: I have different cars with different models in my database.
Car id is mysql id associated with the car and it's unique.
The situation I'm facing is number 2 and my issue is what you exactly just said "get all the reservations for that car and check whether it is having the same (or between) reservation." In my Car model I have `return $this->hasMany('User','car_user');`

Comment: So why don't you just try writing a (select all where car_id ="your carid") query?

Comment: I've added how to write the query in laravel to the answer

Comment: How do I assign the car to the requested time and next time a user requests a car I can loop through the cars' reservation time. One by one. I'm lost in checking whether it's having same reservation, not checking my reservation table to check any overlapping.... Sorry just saw your edit. Where should this query go ?

Comment: Please explain me how you assign your car to the time slot. ? A better way of doing this is creating relationship between car and time_slot. And save them in a different table. I thought that table is reservation. Add the car id to the reservation table.

Comment: If it is done that way you can retrieve the data as i described.

Comment: So I should create car_reservation pivot table then how do I loop through that to check the time all the cars with time? Can my original function be modified to do that ? My plan is when the user wants to reserve a black BMW and in my database I have 2 black BMWs. I wish to have a function to check only these two cars and if they are available then the usr_id will be assigned with BMW_id.

Comment: Next user can submit same request and the loop will check again. If the second  user wants the car in a different time then he can get either one. If he wants the car in the same time as the first user, the function will skip the assigned bmw

Comment: Yes you can! Then also add the user_id to the reservation table. Don't add  it in the car table. Your car table should be the model of your car. So don't add relationships to that. Always it's better to add relationships in a separate table. Try reading about normalization of databases.

Comment: See i edited the answer. You might need to consider about normalization. Not a big thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132294/discussion-between-leo0019-and-gayan-sandaruwan-de-silva).

Comment: Ok let me make it easy for you :) and sorry for the long discussion. Imagine there are two back cars in my database. 
A- is available from 5-9 
B- is available from 1-4 

a user wants a back car so he requested and my function found a back car for him(A). then he requested it from 2-4. (A) is not available from 2-4 so the response will be "sorry this car isn't available." How can I avoid this solution ? My solution is to first loop through (A)(B)'s reservations then pick the best one works for the user. But I don't know how to execute this